# Accessing pinia store through a parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, pinia

I am following a tutorial on udemy. But instead of using Vue 2 and Vuex I use Vue 3 and Pinia. It works almost. One thing I can't seem to fix like the writer does.

I made a child component that has a click event to delete a task in pinia. The thing is
he uses
 `@click="$store.dispatch('deleteTask', task.id)"`

And he states that you don't need to import the vuex store etc in the child component. But when trying to do this with pinia i always get a deleteTask not defined. When importing the store in the child component it works. Is this even possible with pinia? I us:

`@click.stop='useTasks.deleteTask(task.id)'`

Comment: You didn't post the rest of the component, which is relevant, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . $store refers to the only Vuex store, while there can be many of them in Pinia, and they aren't supposed to be accessed globally. useTask is not a store but a function that returns a store. Generally you aren't supposed to write this code 'useTasks.deleteTask(task.id)' in template and so not access a store there. Instead there can be some function in a comp that does that

Comment: `useTasks` is a function which returns the store instance when called. `useTasks.deleteTask` is undefined, whereas `useTasks().deleteTask` is defined. The handler should be `@click.stop="useTasks().deleteTask(task.id)"`.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from the udemy guy. And i searched on pinia docs for more answers but it seems you always need to import the store in the child component. Not like you could doe with vuex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).